# Conditional probability problemm

Tags: probability

Task: Alice and Bob agreed to meet between 3 and 4 o'clock. When Alice come to place, she will wait 10 minutes. If bob will not arrive in those 10 minutes, Alice leaves and vise versa.
What is probability that alice and bob will meet?

My attempt to solve:
Assume minutes correspond to descrete random variable, so sample space is countable {1..60}
We are interesteed in Probability that Bob arrives within 10 minutes after Alice arrive so
`P(a<B<=a+10|A=a)`, where P(B=b)=1/60 and P(A=a)=1/60.
Assume Alice arrives at minute 1, so `P(1<B<=11|A=1)= 10*1/60*1/60=(1/6)*(1/60)`.
There are 50 such events + 9 events for waiting 9,8..1 minutes coresponding to Alice ariving at 51,52..59 minutes.
Thus
`P(a<B<=a+10|A=a)= 50*1/6*1/60+9*1/60*1/60+ 8*1/60*1/60+..+1*1/60*1/60`
And answer to the question is `2* P(a<B<=a+10|A=a)`

Do I solve it in right way?

Comment: Please, at least, remove the typo in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear that the arrival times are discrete (i.e. they arrive at exact minuts). I'd compute the red area proportion in the following image:

[image]

Comment: I just interested in descret:)